# All muc room members are owner

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

In my XMPP client all members of a newly created room are by default getting `owner` affiliation. How can I assign member affiliation to everyone by default except the actual owner?

Following is what my node's mod_muc module says -

```
[{access, muc},
 {default_room_options,
  [{persistent, true}, {public, true},
   {anonymous, false}]},
 {access_create, muc_create},
 {access_persistent, muc_create},
 {access_admin, muc_admin}]
```

Comment: I guess that's a server-side misconfiguration

Comment: @vautee Yes, that's related to ejabberd server. I've posted my server's configuration for mod_muc. I am not sure what did I put there which caused this.

Comment: Please, you need to also show the part of your config file where you defined access rules.